# JSON syntax error in Opencart 2.0.3.2 RC multi store

Tags: json, opencart, opencart2.x, multistore

Via github I installed the 2.0.3.2. RC version on my digital ocean VPS. All seemed to work fine, but just like many others i got problems with the JSON syntax error. I spent hours reading through forum pages about

- API users that have to be made
- API users that have to be appointed
- Maintenance mode that had to be switched off
- the json = array(); solution
- and cUrl loopback restrictions (including the vqmod curl loopback workaround ) http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=191&t=146714

All of these solutions didn't seem to work... When i finally found out that I had my VPS access restricted on IP address and removed this restriction the order history update seemed to work fine so I assumed ALL was ok.

Today when I tried to edit an order, the same following error came popping up. So I started going over the forums again for a solution.

While heavily frustrated trying things i bumped in to this strange behaviour. When on the first page of order editing I get the error, but when I select the standard shop... all works fine... I can edit the order exactly how i want... but when i switch the option back to the store the order was placed in... it responds directly with the same error (see attachment).

I'm not sure if there are any other multistore users that are on 2.0.3+ that have shops that are working fine?

Could you think with me? Could it be something with the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy? All suggestions are welcome!

[image: Chrome Error]

Comment: Opencart 2.0.3.2 version is not released by OpenCart official. So, I think, You need to use OpenCart 2.0.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings, edit your store (not Default), 
and on first tab (Genaral), make sure that your SSL URL is set.

If you don't have SSL, then set the same value as Store URL.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a cross origin policy issue as you mentioned.  I solved this issue on 1.5.6 as well as the crossdomain cookie issue (which has never worked properly to my knowledge on any version) by adding:

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
```

In the AJAX request as well as setting `access-control-allow-credentials` on the receiving header.  The trick here is that for cross origin headers to work this way you need to explicitly declare the URL which is allowed (i.e., `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` will **not** work).  The next trick is that you don't want to accept these headers from any and every URL.

To work around this, I added something like this to the `manual.php` controller - which in 2.0+ would be `api/order.php` (and for cross domain cookie sharing `common/header.php` as well):

```
$this->load->model('setting/store');
$allowed[] = trim(HTTP_SERVER,'/');
$allowed[] = trim(HTTPS_SERVER, '/');
$stores = $this->model_setting_store->getStores();
foreach ($stores as $store) {
    if ($store['url']) $allowed[] = strtolower(trim($store['url'],'/'));
    if ($store['ssl']) $allowed[] = strtolower(trim($store['ssl'],'/'));
}
if (isset($this->request->server['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $url_parts = parse_url($this->request->server['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $origin = strtolower($url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host']);
    if (in_array($origin,$allowed)) {
        header("access-control-allow-origin: " . $origin);
        header("access-control-allow-credentials: true");
    } else {
        header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
    }
} else {
    header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
}
header("access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header("access-control-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
```

This would basically create an array of all acceptable URLs and if the request is valid it sets the HTTP headers explicitly to allow cookies and session data.  This was primarily a fix for cross-domain cookie sharing but I have a feeling it may be helpful for working around the 2.0 api issue as well.

Comment: Thank u billynoah for your reply. In what function/class should i put this code? I can only find the file: admin/controller/sale/order.php. there is a public funtion api(). Tried it there, but it didn't work. in what file do i change the ajax request?

Comment: If you are familiar with php and apache and take the time to understand the framework and what you're trying to do you should be able to figure this out.  If not, you might want to consider hiring a developer or visiting the opencart support forums to learn how to implement a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of me found out the api calls are always done through ssl, all I had to do is add the normal store url in the SSL field in the settings from the store (not the main).